# How to make a listview entry blink after scrolling to it?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have a listview in my app and I want to be able to scroll to a position in the listview and then perform a blink animation at that entry to highlight it to the user.

The issue I'm having it that the blinking animation doesn't happen if the entry that's scroll to is outside of the listview's view. I understand that the listview is efficient because it doesn't load all the entries at once, so this is likely the reason the animation doesn't occur. How can I get around this issue?

**Scroll to code:**

```
    //Changes to tab with listview
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
    //Get index to scroll to
    int selectIndex = whitelistFragment.getWhitelistTableHelper().getListViewEntryIndex(entryString);
    //If the entry exists
    if(selectIndex != -1) {
        //Scroll to index
        whitelistFragment.getWhitelistTableHelper().getListView().setSelection(selectIndex);

        //Make entry blink several times
        View entryView = helperFunctions.getViewByPosition(selectIndex, whitelistFragment.getWhitelistTableHelper().getListView());
        Animation blinkAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.blink);
        entryView.startAnimation(blinkAnimation);
    }
```

**Blink.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="5"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView is not efficient, you should use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). It have method scrollToPosition(). Later in onBindViewHolder check if position == blink postion and run animation on itemView. You could use startDelay for better look.

Comment: I'd rather not refactor my code to use a RecyclerView just so I can do a simple blink animation. Isn't there a workaround I can use?

Comment: I actually implemented a ScrollListener and performed the animation after the scroll was done and now it works.

Comment: How many items in your list you have? RecyclerView is realy great view with great performance and is quite easy to migrate to it.